# Pass additional parameter to template using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, parameter-passing

I have the following directive:

```
app.directive("actTemplate", function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: "/views/myTemplate.html"
};
});
```

how can i pass additional parameter to myTemplate so:

```
<div>
{{aditionalParam}}

...

</div>
```

takes the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define

```
app.directive("actTemplate", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: "/views/myTemplate.html"
    scope: {
      foo: '=boo'
    }
  };
});
```

Template

```
<div>
  {{foo}}
</div>
```

Use

```
<actTemplate boo="lalala" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify that your directive should create it's inner scope. Scope variable could then be shared in single or double binding way (see [directive scope binding doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive))

```
app.directive("actTemplate", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            additionalParam: '='
        },
        template: "<div>{{additionalParam}}</div>"
    };
});
```

Then "call" your directive with this dashed syntaxe:

```
<div act-template additional-param="foobar">
```

You can have one-way binding (controller -> directive) like in this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ArnaudRinquin/BskAu/).

Or two way data binding (controller <-> directive) , like in [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/ArnaudRinquin/BskAu/3/).